# Redmine CKEditor Image upload Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError Windows

Tags: ckeditor, imagemagick, redmine, redmine-plugins

I recently installed the Bitnami Redmine 2.6.0. for Windows. After some test I started installing two plugins clipboard_image_paste and redmine_ckeditor.

At first I had some troubles to install them but everything worked out at the end.

```
C:\redmine-2.6.0-1\apps\redmine\htdocs>bundle install --without development test
 postgresql sqlite
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using activesupport 3.2.19
Using builder 3.0.4
Using activemodel 3.2.19
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.5
Using rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.2.2
Using actionpack 3.2.19
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 3.2.19
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using activerecord 3.2.19
Using activeresource 3.2.19
Using climate_control 0.0.3
Using cocaine 0.5.5
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using daemons 1.1.9
Using eventmachine 1.0.3
Using htmlentities 4.3.2
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using json 1.8.1
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 3.2.19
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
Using kaminari 0.16.1
Using mysql2 0.3.11
Using net-ldap 0.3.1
Using paperclip 3.5.4
Using ruby-openid 2.3.0
Using rack-openid 1.4.1
Using rack-raw-upload 1.1.1
Using bundler 1.7.0
Using rails 3.2.19
Using rbpdf 1.18.1
Using redcarpet 2.3.0
Using request_store 1.0.5
Using sass 3.4.9
Using sass-rails 3.2.6
Using rich 1.4.6
Using rmagick 2.13.1
Using thin 1.6.1
Updating files in vendor/cache
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development, test, postgresql and sqlite were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

C:\redmine-2.6.0-1\apps\redmine\htdocs>ruby bin/rake redmine:plugins RAILS_ENV=p
roduction
Migrating clipboard_image_paste (Clipboard image paste)...
Migrating redmine_ckeditor (Redmine CKEditor plugin)...
```

The bundle was installed successfully.

I started testing everything and then I got an error when I want to upload an image via CKEditor. A new window opens with the URL

```
http://localhost:8010/redmine/rich/files/?CKEditor=issue_description&CKEditorFuncNum=2&default_style=original&allowed_styles=thumb%2Crich_thumb%2Coriginal&insert_many=false&type=image&scoped=true&scope_type=Project&scope_id=1&viewMode=grid
```

I choose a file from a folder. It tries to upload but after half a second I get the error message:

```
Could not upload your file:

-rich_file

Paperclip:Errors::NotIdentifiedbyImageMagickError
```

Has someone an idea what I can do to make it work?

And please explain in detail, I am not used to do such things!

Thank you

I just went through the hole process again and I noticed this. The second part of initializing the plugins this time showed:

> C:\Bitnami\redmine-2.6.0-2\apps\redmine\htdocs>ruby bin/rake
>   redmine:plugins RAI LS_ENV=production Migrating clipboard_image_paste
>   (Clipboard image paste)... Migrating redmine_ckeditor (Redmine
>   CKEditor plugin)...
>   == CreateRichRichImages: migrating ===========================================
>   -- create_table(:rich_rich_images)
>   -> 0.0781s
>   == CreateRichRichImages: migrated (0.0781s) ==================================
>
> == AddUriCacheToRichImage: migrating =========================================
>   -- add_column(:rich_rich_images, :uri_cache, :text)
>   -> 0.1719s
>   == AddUriCacheToRichImage: migrated (0.1875s) ================================
>
> == RefactorImageToFile: migrating ============================================
>   -- rename_table(:rich_rich_images, :rich_rich_files)
>   -> 0.0313s
>   -- rename_column(:rich_rich_files, :image_file_name, :rich_file_file_name)
>   -> 0.1719s
>   -- rename_column(:rich_rich_files, :image_content_type, :rich_file_content_type)
>
> -> 0.1875s
>   -- rename_column(:rich_rich_files, :image_file_size, :rich_file_file_size)
>   -> 0.2188s
>   -- rename_column(:rich_rich_files, :image_updated_at, :rich_file_updated_at)
>   -> 0.1719s
>   -- add_column(:rich_rich_files, :simplified_type, :string, {:default=>"file"})
>   -> 0.1406s
>   == RefactorImageToFile: migrated (0.9220s) ===================================

Maybe someone can make sense out of it...

Comment: the function "browse and upload file" is working. The file is uploaded, but afterwards when i click on the file the image is not shown.

Comment: I downloaded the new Bitmani Redmine stack and started the installation from scratch but I still receive the same error when I try to upload an image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in the system environment variables the path where the ImageMagick identify.exe executable is located (e.g. C:\ImageMagick\bin).

Restart the server and it works for me.